# How do I negate \curlywedge

Tags: symbols

When I put `\not\curlywedge` I get

[image]

I tried something like `\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{\nprec}` but the line goes the wrong way.

Comment: How does `\newcommand{\ncurlywedge}{\mathbin{\not\negthickspace\curlywedge}}` with `$A \ncurlywedge B$` strike you?

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is solved by comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're using `\curlywedge` as a relation symbol, since you want to negate it. Note that `\curlywedge` is, as defined by `amssymb`, a binary operation symbol, so its spacing rules are quite different from a relation one. For instance, if you say

```
\not\mathrel{\curlywedge}
```

you get

[image]

However, this is not completely satisfying. Here's my proposal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\bcw}{\mathrel{\curlywedge}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nbcw}{\mathrel{\vphantom{/}\mathpalette\ncbw@\relax}}
\newcommand{\ncbw@}[2]{%
  \ooalign{$\m@th#1\bcw$\cr\hidewidth$\m@th#1\mkern1mu/$\hidewidth\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A \bcw B \nbcw C_{A\bcw B\nbcw C}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The slash is moved a bit to the right in order to avoid it being almost tangent to the left part.

If you're using the symbols as binary operations, just replace `\mathrel` with `\mathbin`.

I recommend using a more semantic name (the suggested one is just for writing the code) anyway.

---

If you prefer the `\not` character, that's more slanted than `/`,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\bcw}{\mathrel{\curlywedge}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nbcw}{\mathrel{\vphantom{\not}\mathpalette\ncbw@\relax}}
\newcommand{\ncbw@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1{\not}\hphantom{=}$}%
  \ooalign{$\m@th#1\bcw$\cr\hidewidth$\m@th#1\mkern1.5mu\copy\z@$\hidewidth\cr}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A \bcw B \nbcw C_{A\bcw B\nbcw C}$

\end{document}
```

[image]